# making path finding algorithm with multi-thread

Tags: multithreading, algorithm, multi-agent

I'd like to make algorithm that works like this image

http://i.imgur.com/lntXzuF.gif

I've learned A*, Dijkstra, Breadth-First-Search, and Best-First-Search with SINGLE thread.

is there any reference or algorithm that I can refer to?

Comment: That is Multi Agent not Multi Thread !!! so google for multi agent system/algorithms ...

Comment: Well, you can try two approaches: 1) (optimization problem) single controller (master) establishing the best routes for all agents (the only way to guarantee optimal solution); 2) (multi-agent approach) let the agents find their best way as possible adapting along the way - you need to improve your question to get a better answer.  regarding a multi-thread algorithm for shortest path you can start a literature review by this article: http://www.cc.gatech.edu/~bader/papers/AdvancedShortestPath-MTAAP2007.pdf